# EclipseLink 2.1.3, Oracle 11g, return PK after persist with container managed persistence

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink 2.1.3 with a container managed EntityManager to interface with an Oracle 11g DB.

I want to have an Entity's @Id variable updated immediately after I call persist() on the EM.

What is the correct strategy to do so with an Oracle DB?

None of the examples I've found on this site deal with this problem with container managed persistence.

The Entity looks like this:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ANNOUNCEMENT_DELIVERY_LOG")
    public class AnnouncementDeliveryLog implements Serializable {

        @Id
        private BigDecimal id;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ANNOUNCEMENT_ID ")
        private Announcements announcement;

        public AnnouncementDeliveryLog() {
        }

    }
```

Do I need to add something like the following?

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ANNOUNCEMENT_DELIVERY_LOG_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="ANNOUNCEMENT_DELIVERY_LOG_SEQ", sequenceName="ANNOUNCEMENT_DELIVERY_LOG_SEQ")
```

To persist the Entity I'm just calling persist().  Do I also need to call flush()?

Comment: Can you show us the entity's class PK field definition including its annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to provide a `@SequenceGenerator` annotation in order that JPA automatically assigns a new ID to the entity during `persist()`.

A flush is not necessary.

Comment: Does my suggested @SequenceGenerator annotation look correct?

Comment: Yes, if the corresponding sequence is named ANNOUNCEMENT_DELIVERY_LOG_SEQ